# How to prevent two same divs in HTML from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I am working on an HTML page that has two separated columns. And I need to print the texts in the two columns pair by pair becasue I am going to build a JSP based on this HTML. Now I run into some problem that every time I try to print a new pair of text, it will overlap with the previous one. And I have tried to add the `clear:both` in the left-col and right-col style, it still doesn't work out well.

Here is my CSS:

```css
header {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  font-size: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.container p,
ul,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#left-col {
  width: calc(30% - 1.5em);
  text-align: right;
  color: #74afe0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

#right-col {
  width: calc(70% - 2.5em);
  bottom: 1em;
  height: calc(100% - 80px - 1em);
  top: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 1em;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 3px solid #74afe0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#list {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>CSS Layout Project</header>
<div class="container">
  <section id="left-col">
    <div id="title">
      <p>
        <h2><b>Course Description</b></h2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="right-col">
    <p>
      <h2><b>Acdemic Integrity</b></h2>
    </p>
    <div id="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="left-col">
    <div id="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="right-col">
    <div id="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>&copy; Copyright by XXXXXX</footer>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @j08691 Thank you! So there is no way I can use the same id multiple times with no overlapping?

Comment: use `class="class-name"` instead if you want to use it for more than one element. an element can have only **one, unique** `id`, but an endless number of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use fixed positioning on those left/right sections. It's kind of hard to tell you what to do since I don't know what your ideal layout of this page is supposed to look like, but removing fixed positioning and applying flex to the parent with `flex-wrap: wrap` lets you use the existing CSS and have it layout in a way that I'm guessing is closer to whatever your end goal is. I also removed some unnecessary CSS and added a margin-bottom to `.container` so that there is room for the fixed footer.

Also changed your id's to classes, as others have pointed out that you should only have 1 id per page.

```css
header {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  font-size: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container p,
ul,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-col {
  width: calc(30% - 1.5em);
  text-align: right;
  color: #74afe0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right-col {
  width: calc(70% - 2.5em);
  bottom: 1em;
  height: calc(100% - 80px - 1em);
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 3px solid #74afe0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.content {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>CSS Layout Project</header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="left-col">
    <div id="title">
      <p>
        <h2><b>Course Description</b></h2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <p>
      <h2><b>Acdemic Integrity</b></h2>
    </p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="left-col">
    <div class="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <div class="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>&copy; Copyright by XXXXXX</footer>
```

You can also achieve a similar layout using `float` instead of `flex`

```css
header {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  font-size: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container p,
ul,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-col {
  width: calc(30% - 1.5em);
  text-align: right;
  color: #74afe0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.right-col {
  width: calc(70% - 2.5em);
  bottom: 1em;
  height: calc(100% - 80px - 1em);
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 3px solid #74afe0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.content {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>CSS Layout Project</header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="left-col">
    <div id="title">
      <p>
        <h2><b>Course Description</b></h2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <p>
      <h2><b>Acdemic Integrity</b></h2>
    </p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="left-col">
    <div class="content">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <div class="content">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>&copy; Copyright by XXXXXX</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: @TommyTang awesome! no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

All #id tags must be used for one element. If you want to target multiple elements, use a class.

Comment: Right, but are you sure by doing this, the problem will solve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick and dirty possible way to fix this.
Change `id` to `class` for `left-col` and `right-col`, and add `float: left;` to them in css.

**HTML:**

```
<header>CSS Layout Project</header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="left-col">
    <div id="title">
      <p>
        <h2><b>Course Description</b></h2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content1">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <p>
      <h2><b>Acdemic Integrity</b></h2>
    </p>
    <div id="content2">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="left-col">
    <div id="content2">
      <p>fields</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-col">
    <div id="content3">
      <p>For years I have been driving an old used car with a lot of mileage, and I hate it. It gets me where I need to go, but I’m tired of fixing leaks and broken parts all the time. It's annoying that I have to take it to the mechanic every time. Even
        when they take care of everything, I know in a week I’ll just end up going back there.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>&copy; Copyright by XXXXXX</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  font-size: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #74afe0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.container p,
ul,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-col {
  width: calc(30% - 1.5em);
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  color: #74afe0;
/*   position: fixed; */
  left: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right-col {
  width: calc(70% - 2.5em);
  bottom: 1em;
  float: right;
  height: calc(100% - 80px - 1em);
  top: 80px;
/*   position: fixed; */
  right: 1em;
/*   overflow: scroll; */
  border-left: 3px solid #74afe0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#list {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```